# MySQL python connector code aborts without error (Code from the MySQL documentation)

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mysql-python

I was trying to use the python connector code given in the MySQL documentation and test it on a small database already created, but it aborts. The code is just supposed to connect to the db and add a new email adress.

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode


cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='pwd', host='localhost', database='db')

cursor = cnx.cursor()  

add_email = ("INSERT INTO employee(MID, Email) VALUES (%s,%s)")
email_details = (NULL, "a@a.de")

cursor.execute(add_email, email_details)

cnx.commit()
input("data entered successfully")
cnx.close()
```

By setting breakpoints I found out that the problem probably lies in the `cursor.execute()` statement. (I used Null as the first `%s` since MID is Auto Incrementing btw)

Comment: What is `NULL` in your code? BTW, inserting to table with autoincrementing column can be rewritten as `"INSERT INTO employee(Email) VALUES (%s)"` (you don't need to pass `None`/`NULL` explicitly)

Comment: @EugenePrimako Thanks for correcting the typos. "What is NULL in your code?" ---> I learned that NULL is used to give something to the database when the value in it is autoincrementing and thus thought it would be the same in this case. Now I know better. I doesn't seem to solve the problem though (I used `employee(Email) VALUES (%s)` and `email_details = ("a@a.de")`

Comment: You are right concerning `NULL`, but in Python context `None` is used instead. And one more question: what do you mean by "aborts"? (How do you run the given piece of code - as standalone script, as separate commands in Python interpreter, etc?)

Comment: Indeed @EugenePrimako. I'm even surprised `NULL` does not err out by Python for an unknown object. Maybe that is the error the OP is receiving.

Comment: @EugenePrimako and Parfait Using `None` instead of `NULL` did actually solve the problem and everything worked fine. Thank you very much for helping me out. Have a good one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem `NULL` (for the autoincrementing "MID") needs to be replaced with `None`.